# C# Resharper - Warning on too long line

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, rider

As a team we'd like to have a "soft long lines" setting: Instead of hard-wrapping a too long code line, we'd love to see a warning so that a developer can take action - or intentionally leave the code as it is.

What we found out so far: you can either hard-wrap or not. But we did not find the space in-between - to just be warned.

We are running a mixed Visual Studio with ReSharper and Rider environment with common code style rules in a "DotSettings" file.

Answer (score 1):

I've filled the feature request in YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-495222/Add-the-warning-that-the-line-is-too-long, you are welcome to comment on it and vote.
Thank you!

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but is helpful and should be a comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure ReSharper or Visual Studio can't warn you about long lines but take a look at Sonar static code analyzers (SonarLint or SonarQube) They have a rule for [long lines](https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/tag/convention/RSPEC-103/)

They have an [extension for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.SonarLintforVisualStudio2022) but I have found adding the [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SonarAnalyzer.CSharp/) works well and can be [configured](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-dotnet?tab=readme-ov-file#standalone-nuget)

Comment: This sounds like a good compromise. Will try it 

Comment: This sounds great. I installed it and I see many new warnings but that long lines rule doesn't seem to work. Do you need to enable it somehow? I can't find any indicator on that line that the rule is disabled by default. Odd.